# JPanel JButton doesn't always show

Tags: java, swing

Alright I have no idea whats going on here. JButtons sometimes show when I compile my program and other times I can only see the JPanel with no buttons, if I have multiple buttons a random amount of them show, I have no idea what is causing this. I also just found that if I minimize the JFrame and Maximize the buttons will eventually show up.

```
public void controlPanel(){

    JPanel jp = new CreateJPanel();
    Color color = new Color(0,40,0);

    jp.setSize(f.getWidth()/2, (int) (f.getHeight() * 0.15));   
    jp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(color, 1));
    jp.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    jp.setLocation(0, (int) (f.getHeight()* 0.50));
    jp.add (new JButton ("Button1"));
    f.add(jp);

}
```

JFrame class

```
public class CreateTranseperantJFrame extends JFrame{

public CreateTranseperantJFrame(){

    this.setSize(1420, 820);
    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,1));
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.requestFocus();

    }
}
```

Comment: `this.setLayout(null);` is a good start to your problem.  Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Are you overriding `paint` or `paintComponent` or any other paint method? Make sure you cal `setVisible` on our frame LAST after the UI is initialised or call `revalidate` (although if you're using a null layout, this is pointless) and `repaint` AFTER you've add new content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar problem once.

In my case, due to many subcomponents it was important for me to validate the component containing all my stuff.

In your case, it would translate into:

```
jp.validate();
```

at the end of your method "controlPanel"

**EDIT:**
It turns out that in most cases it should suffice to validate the upmost component, as you stated in your comment.

Thus:

```
this.validate();
```

at the end of your constructor CreateTranseperantJFrame()

Additionally it could very well be possible that you have to .validate() all components that show this behaviour.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you that worked I had to validate my JFrame but it worked.

Comment: Glad I could help. I will edit the JFrame into my Answer, so that others with the same problem will find their answer faster.